# installing z3 haskell bindings on windows

Tags: windows, haskell, z3

I've followed the [docs](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3#readme) for z3 to install it onto my windows machine. The output says `Z3 was successfully built.` but when I try to install Haskell bindings by running `cabal install z3` I get the error:

```
* Missing (or bad) header file: z3.h
* Missing (or bad) C library: z3
```

But I've followed the guide to install z3 and it seems to have worked? The other methods in the z3 docs usually have an 'install' step, should the instructions for windows have an install step as well? I naively tried 'nmake install' but that did not work.

What do I need for the cabal install command to work.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [`z3` README on Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/z3#installation), you need to specify `--extra-lib-dirs` and `--extra-include-dirs` to tell Cabal where to find your Z3 library and header files, respectively, for example:

```
cabal install z3 --extra-include-dirs=C:\z3-4.8.0-x64-win\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\z3-4.8.0-x64-win\bin
```

If you use a binary release, these directories are found in the extracted archive. (I don’t see a mention in the Z3 docs of where they would end up when you build with VS.)